# Chrome Smart Site Search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search, google-api, google-search

I noticed that a couple of sites have a built in Chrome search feature. If I type stackoverflow.com and then press space in the address bar I get: [image: Chrome site search]

---

---

---

Which takes me to this: [image: SO search]

How is this done, the major sites like Stackoverflow and github have this feature, but sites that don't implement this default to a regular google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line, which is in the HTML of every Stack Overflow page, is responsible:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

The format of that XML file is documented here:

http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1

Comment: It is supported to varying degrees by some other browsers as well. Chrome is the only one I'm aware of that'll pick it up without any prompting, though.